# Separate string by array

Tags: php

I have no idea on how to do this, it'd probably use an explode but that'd not do exactly as I wanted.

Say I have a string:

```
a,1,1,0,0;0,1,1,0,0;r,1,1,0,0;
```

and I have an array:

```
a = atv
p = 330c
U = blista
c = BMW
D = bobcat
r = charger
```

I'd like it so that when it's called as a function on that string like `seperateString($string);` that it'd return something like "atv, charger"

I've tried some searching but to no avail have I found something which would return a string specific to the array.

Comment: To clarify, you want to output elements of the array based on their keys being found in the input string. In your example, does this mean that the numbers 1 and 0 are ignored, since the only matching keys are "a" and "r" in the array?

Comment: Also, are the input string semicolons (;) supposed to be commas (,) or do they have significance?

Comment: The numbers have no significance in this example, but are required elsewhere

Comment: @PwnageAtPwn: If a provided solution works, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "a,1,1,0,0;0,1,1,0,0;r,1,1,0,0;";
$array = array('a' => 'atv',
  'p' => '330c',
  'U' => 'blista',
  'c' => 'BMW',
  'D' => 'bobcat',
  'r' => 'charger');

function separateString($array, $string) {
  $result = array();
  $chunks = preg_split('/[,;]/', $string);
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    if (array_key_exists($chunk, $array)) {
      $result[] = $array[$chunk];
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

print_r(separateString($array, $string));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => atv
    [1] => charger
)
```

[codepad example](http://codepad.org/f0mp29SL)

Comment: Works perfectly but you can replace the second loop with `if (array_key_exists($chunk, $array)) $result[] = $array[$chunk];`

Answer (score 0):

The information you posted wasn't that great to go off of, but here's a start:

```
$string = "a,1,1,0,0;0,1,1,0,0;r,1,1,0,0;";

class Utility
{
    protected static $classes = array(
        'a' => 'atv',
        'p' => '330c',
        'U' => 'blista',
        'c' => 'BMW',
        'D' => 'bobcat',
        'r' => 'charger'
    );    

    public static function separateString($string)
    {
        $groups = explode(';', $string);

        foreach ($groups as $group) {

            $classId = array_shift(explode(',', $group));

            if (array_key_exists($classId, self::$classes)) {
                $classes[] = self::$classes[$classId];
            }
        }

        return (isset($classes)) ? $classes : array();    
    }
}


$classes = Utility::separateString($string);

var_dump($classes);

/*
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(3) "atv"
[1]=>
string(7) "charger"
}
*/
```